# Wordpress WP-Types Toolest - deactives Front-end Display

Tags: wordpress, types

how to disable the front-end display box in the backend of custom types?

(using WP-Types.com Toolset Plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Edit and custom post type you have created using [Toolset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) Plugin. Do as shown in below image.

[image]